Converting from 1-phase to 3-phase
In the Netherlands, the energy company says that, in order to convert my 1-phase electrical configuration into a 3-phase one, I need to add a 4-pole 40A main switch for their safety.
In the picture below, you can see how my electrical box looks like.
Electrical box arrangement
The question is: am I right in concluding that I need to split the wire for L1 and N and connect it both to the inputs of the RCD and those of the 4-pole switch (as I drew it in the pic)? I suppose then the energy company will come and connect the other 2 phase wires to the other 2 inputs of the 4-pole switch.
Then, it sounds like I'll need to include another RCD for the 3-phase switch as well.

Is my conclusion correct?

Usually an energy company will have very specific standards on how to add and even which makes and models you can use.

@crip659 they gave me this part: https://www.elektramat.nl/abb-hoofdschakelaar-4-polig-40a-rood-sd-204-40/?channable=0141ac696400313236343104&bg_source=ga&bg_campaign=17673967332&bg_kw=-mi-9214030-pi-401043993-ppi-&bg_source_id=&gad_source=1#details and they don't do this kind of work, "we are not electricians", they told me.

They are obviously electricians.  What they mean is their job is to hand you the pointy end of a live cable, and not to build your house.   It's nice that they gave you a switch instead of requiring you to buy one that conforms to their complicated standards.

Remember unless you have a main power disconnect before that panel, those wires will have enough power to ruin your day.

The six circuit breakers in this panel: Do they feed six other circuit breaker panels? Or do they feed your lights and wall outlets directly?  What does "Groep" mean?  I know what the word means, but what does it mean in regards to your home?

You should ask the company what they will do, but I would expect they will entirely replace the cable you have now.  If you are upgrading an occupied site, it would be wise to put the new main cutoff in a separate box.  This will make it easier to upgrade the entire main breaker box or consumer unit or whatever it's called in Dutch.  You can turn off the new main switch and have complete freedom to work on or replace the main panel.  You should discuss this with your electrician, assuming you're not doing this all yourself.  I assume you're not keeping that tiny panel when tripling your service capacity.
How? Again, I'm guessing what they will do and you can ask them! But I would think the company will remove the old supply and bring the new cable to the new switch in the new separate box.  While they are working (at a coordinated time) you can disconnect the old supply from your old panel and connect the old panel to the new main switch box.  When they are finished you turn that on and you are back to normal.  Then you can later install a bigger panel, switch to it, start using the new phases, all without the power company being involved.
As for RCDs, again I don't know Netherlands practice.   If you must have a 3-phase RCD for the entire site, I guess put it in the new box with the new switch?  But I would think it wise to split the house into more than 3 RCD zones, so if you can do that and avoid having a single RCD for the entire 3-phase supply, that may be preferable -- again, if it's allowed, which I don't know.

In my interpretation what they want is a 4-pole RCD that they can terminate the new 4 phase cable from the new meter in your electrical panel.
At this time there is no need to put anything in the unused two phases.
Connecting to those other phases can be done as part of later work to load balance the phases or when you install an EVSE or an induction stove.

Not sure if I was clear enough, but I already concluded that I had to leave those unused 2 phases unconnected, but it looks like I still need to connect the L1 and N to the new 4-pole switch.

When you say "I need to connect" .... are you planning to do this yourself or hiring an electrician?  And, what do you mean "I already concluded ....." ?    Why are you installing 3-phase if you are not going to connect them?   What is the big plan?  Do you have an idea of the final state and how you will get there?

@jay613 I first wanted to figure out whether the job was simple enough for me to do or whether I needed an electrician. My background is in EE and I've worked with high voltages before.

@jay613 onto your 2nd question, we're going to install an induction cooking plate in our kitchen, so the company doing this said we need a 3-phase system. However, the electricians we hired to do this said our home was 1-phase and needed 3-phase, so we needed the energy company to come and connect the new system to our electrical box. However, they failed to mention that the energy company needed a 4-pole main switch to be installed beforehand... Work that these electricians could've done but failed to inform me about it.

@jay613 Therefore, I wanted to understand the way this switch needs to be connected. Is that clear enough? From what I understood from this answer, it's concluding that I simply need to leave the remaining phases unconnected, which I already wrote in my question.

Got it.  Well, the most likely scenario is what I wrote in my answer.  Company will de-energize your old cable, bring in a new, de-energized 3-phase cable that you will connect to your new switch, you will remove the old cable, connect your circuits (Groups) to any of the new three phases, they will turn on the new on and you will turn on your new switch.   Everything in your question about splitting and moving the old wire is probably not correct.  But a local electrician will know more about the details of how your electric company works.
